# Cannot call a function in a spawned thread because it "does not fulfill the required lifetime"

Tags: multithreading, closures, rust, lifetime

I can run this code

```
fn testf(host: &str) {}

fn start(host: &str) {
    testf(host);
    testf(host);
}
```

but for some reason, I can't run this one:

```
fn testf(host: &str) {}

fn start(host: &str) {
    thread::spawn(move || testf(host));
    thread::spawn(move || testf(host));
}
```

because of the following error

```
src/server.rs:30:5: 30:18 error: the type `[closure@src/server.rs:30:19: 30:38 host:&str]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
src/server.rs:30     thread::spawn(move || testf(host));
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: type must outlive the static lifetime
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Can somebody explain me, what is wrong with it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

Your closure captures a string slice, therefore its environment has lifetime no longer than that of this slice, but [`thread::spawn()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) requires its argument to have static lifetime:

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T> 
    where F: FnOnce() -> T, 
          F: Send + 'static, 
          T: Send + 'static
```

(note the `F: 'static` requirement)

This is necessary because when the thread spawned by `thread::spawn()` gets to run, the string from which the slice is taken may already be destroyed. Rust has actually prevented an error in your code!

There are several ways to fix it.

1) The simplest way would be to clone the string for each thread:

```
fn start(host: &str) {
    {
        let host = host.to_owned();
        thread::spawn(move || testf(&host));
    }
    {
        let host = host.to_owned();
        thread::spawn(move || testf(&host));
    }
}
```

This way each thread receives its own copy of the string which will be destroyed when the thread itself finishes.

2) If you know that your threads should finish before `start()` function ends, you can use a third-party librariy like [crossbeam](https://github.com/aturon/crossbeam) to pass references into spawned threads:

```
extern crate crossbeam;

fn start(host: &str) {
    crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(move || testf(host));
        scope.spawn(move || testf(host));
    });
}
```

This way `start()` will wait until both threads spawns in `scoped()` has finished before returning, making sure that whatever string `host` points to won't be destroyed prematurely.

Previously such functionality was included in the standard library, but the way it was implemented [was found to be unsound](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24385), so it was deprecated; a proper replacement for this functionality is yet to be added back into the standard library.

3) Even another alternative would be to use `Arc<String>` to share the string between threads, but this would require more significant changes outside of `start()`:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn start(host: Arc<String>) {
    {
        let host = host.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || testf(&host));
    }
    {
        let host = host.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || testf(&host));
    }
}
```

With this approach you need to keep your string inside an `Arc` (which is an "atomically reference counted" pointer), so this requires you to change the code which calls `start()`. Cloning is probably better. Of course, if you want to share not `&str` but `&SomeStruct` where `SomeStruct` is large and/or not cloneable, there is no way to avoid scoping xor `Arc`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of thread::spawn function tried to tell me about my problem :)

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T> where F: FnOnce() -> T, F: Send + 'static, T: Send + 'static
```

so, I can fix that using (host: &'static str) insted of (host: &str)

```
fn testf(host: &str) {}

fn start(host: &'static str) {
    thread::spawn(move || testf(host));
    thread::spawn(move || testf(host));
}
```

it works great for me

Comment: Note that this would work only if you always pass string literals to your `start()` function. It won't work, for example, here: `let s: String = "host".to_owned(); start(&s);`.